# I have 15 minutes to present ASP.NET MVC to my colleagues. What topics should I focus on?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I've been using ASP.NET MVC for personal projects since before it hit RTM.

I am preparing a presentation for my colleagues to introduce them to basic concepts of ASP.NET MVC and show them how it could be used in our environment.

My presentation has a 15 minute limit. There is a lot of information to relay (especially if you factor in projects like MVCContrib and various blog posts).

What topics should I focus on?

**Some context:** I work for a digital agency. My colleagues are .NET developers with 3+ years of ASP.NET experience.

**What's been suggested so far:**

- Reasons for wanting to switch to ASP.NET MVC
- Routing
- ActionResults (ability to serve different responses)
- Request-Response internals
- Testability
- Scaffolding (T4 templates)
- Fine-grained control over HTML output
- Separation of concerns ()
- Differences between ASP.NET WebForms and ASP.NET MVC

Comment: Why the downvote? Especially considering it's been 4 years since I asked the question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You only have time for 2 or 3 main points.

The most important concept to grasp is that requests arrive at controllers then the controller **chooses** what view to present the results the **controller** has generated.

The next important concept is that MVC has its big win over the "classic" ASP.NET when you create unit tests for your controllers and the model.  Without this MVC is just another way to skin a cat.

For a final point I would focus on the structure of URLs not because its that important but because we like things that have a clean feel and MVC Urls can do that, this may help generate a positive response.

Avoid going on about there being no server controls (which isn't entirely true) since that is likely to elicite a negative response.  In general avoid mentioning what is doesn't do compared with ASP.NET forms (although there not being any need for Viewstate is worth mentioning in passing).  You know that the benefits out weigh the things that are missing (or unnecessary) but your audience does not.  Keep it positive.

Answer (score 5):

- Routing
- The flexibility of ActionResults
- Hooking up different Views to the same Controller Action (i.e. a Mobile view)

The big Topic of Unit Testing may be too big for a 15 Minute meeting, but if your developers are already using TDD I would add it

Answer (score 5):

I had to write report for my boss justifying why I wanted to use MVC over webforms/ Nettiers. I blogged my report http://ivida.co.uk/2011/05/11/mvc-nhibernate-vs-webforms-nettiers/

I realise you've only got a short time span but you may find some ideas from the list below....

1. Benefits of MVC

ASP.MVC was written in response to criticisms of Web Forms in relation to other development platforms. Whilst Web Forms gives developers a Rapid Application Development framework and was written to ‘mimic’ the development methods used in Win Forms, it made it difficult to implement certain practices implemented in other platforms and seen as fundamental to good development.
1.1.Testable

MVC allows automated unit and integration tests to be written. This has a number of distinct advantages.

a)     Greatly reduces the need for manual testing; the upfront cost of creating unit tests is paid back downstream by significantly reducing the amount of manual testing.

b)     Can be run throughout the development; this is invaluable as it allows the developer to be sure they aren’t introducing breaking changes to the code base.

c)     Gives the developer the confidence to implement changes to the code base as tests will show any bugs.

d)     Leads to a much more rigorous code base as the code has been testing numerous times throughout the development rather than that afforded by sporadic manual testing.

e)     Each test is a FUNCTIONAL requirement encapsulated in code. If there is a requirement that only users with role X can perform activity Y, the test is evidence that this requirement is being met. This becomes invaluable should a developer return to a code base after a period of time as the requirements are directly viewable by running the tests.

A developer can write as little or as much test code based upon the requirements of the project. If a project is exposed to changes in specification then having tests in place significantly speeds up the implementation of changes. For small lower impact developments, automated testing could be scaled back to cover mainly Create/ Update and Delete scenarios rather than Read scenarios.

Writing tests is an art in its own right and one that a developer becomes better at over time. Without writing any test code an experienced developer could create a project using MVC or Web Forms in a similar time. Writing tests would add perhaps 20% to development time, but reduce any time for system testing considerably.

Having tests in place also considerably reduces the time taken to implement changes and if a change is significant may actually allow that change to take place where it would otherwise be seen as either too risky or too time consuming.

1.2.Adheres to principles of good software design

ASP.MVC follows certain well trodden principles of designing good and maintainable software, such as:

```
“Don’t Repeat Yourself (DRY)
“Separation of Concerns” (SoC)
```

Separation of concerns (not mixing UI logic with underlying behaviour) is a fundamental principle that exists to help developers deal with complexity. Mixing different responsibilities within the same object or files (like putting most of your logic in code behind files such as handling edit, cancel and edit post back events) invites maintenance problems and makes that code difficult to change and difficult to read. MVC prescribes where certain types of objects should be written making the resulting code base much cleaner and easier to follow.

1.3.MVC is prescriptive

Because MVC follows good software design principles it is prescriptive about where certain types of code should be developed. This is useful in a team environment in that it standardises project structures much more than in Web Forms. Once developers are familiar with an MVC project structure it becomes obvious where to look for certain types of code. This will make it easier to work on other developer’s code; a) because of the prescription and b) because running the unit tests will ensure that additional developers aren’t breaking existing functionality. It also helps developer make decisions about where certain types of code should be developed and how code should be separated to allow for easier maintenance. The prescriptive nature an MVC project has also proved useful by allowing the developers in this team to talk about issues and problems they face without having to know the detailed implementation of the project.

1.4.MVC enables easy integration with JavaScript frameworks

Since the launch of Google Suggest in 2004 there has been a sea change in client side web development. This change has been about the implementation of AJAX functionality. AJAX (shorthand for Asynchronous JavaScript and XML) is a group of related techniques used on the client side, to create rich interactive and responsive web applications. With AJAX, web applications can retrieve data from the server asynchronously in the background without interfering with the display and behaviour of the existing page. AJAX uses a combination of HTML and CSS to mark up and style information. The DOM is accessed with JavaScript to dynamically display, and to allow the user to interact with, the information presented.

This type of functionality used to be a fairly difficult to programme due to the varying implementation of standards compliance across browsers. This has now become less of an issue a) due to better standards compliance and b) more significantly due to the development of JavaScript frameworks such as JQuery that allow you write code that works on every browser.

The ‘V’ in MVC, stands for ‘View’ and deals only with the front end delivery of HTML and JavaScript. MVC allows the easy integration with JS frameworks such as JQuery and greatly simplifies the creation of rich client side experiences using such frameworks. (Note JQuery now ships as standard with ASP.NET 2010 and Microsoft are now actively and perhaps belatedly contributing to the JQuery code base).

This simplified integration makes it easier to develop user experiences that match the performance users expect on a modern web site. This is a subtle point but is one that I believe we shouldn’t ignore. Our clients will increasingly develop implicit expectations about how they interact with websites based on their use of the wider internet. There are now very few commercial sites that don’t implement AJAX functionality and the slick responsive interface that it affords. Not looking at developing rich front ends, will increasingly make our output compare disfavour-ably with our clients expectations.

1.5.Consumption of the web is changing (fast)

Morgan Stanley predicts that more people will access the web using mobile devices than using fixed internet / desktop by the middle of 2013 (i.e. within 2 1/2 years).

(http://gigaom.files.wordpress.com/2010/04/mobile-chart2.png)

What’s this got to do with MVC? I believe that MVC is a better platform to deliver content to a variety of devices due to its easier implementation of JS libraries and the ease with which it allows the developer to control the contents of the HTTP response (explained in detail below).

1)     Easier implementation of AJAX – a 3G connection on a mobile device doesn’t currently have bandwidth comparable with broadband. AJAX greatly improves the performance of pages over slower connections as you only return the required data (which is formatted by the browser) rather than the data and the entire page.

2)     MVC gives the developer much greater control over the data returned from a request. This is best seen with actual code examples but within two lines of code a developer can return an entire page (with Master Page etc), JSON (JavaScript Object Notation) which is the data format of choice in AJAX requests, XML or any other format required.

Code sample:

```
//Try doing this in webforms

If (IsJson)

{

return this.JSON(model);

}

Else if (IsXml)

{

return new XMLResult(model);

}

else

{

return View(model)l;

}
```

This level of control is much more difficult to achieve using Web Forms. Having tight control over what is returned in the HTTP response simplifies development of content for a range of devices such as for traditional browsers or Smart phone apps, or for applications that sit within other platforms such as SharePoint.
2.1.1.6.MVC uses RESTFul URL’s

MVC gives the developer full control over the URL. With WebForms the URL matches the underlying file structure of the code. With MVC you have what’s known as a ‘Route Registrar’ which is a file that matches URL’s to the resources that will deal with the request.

There are two distinct advantages of having full control over the URL:

i)      If a project has a requirement for human readable URL’s or search engine optimisation then URL control is a big advantage. Consider the following:

www.mywebapplication.com/users/alex.hardman  (i.e. Retrieve user with name alex.hardman)

as opposed to

www.mywebapplication/users/getuser.aspx (name passed in session) or www.mywebapplication/users/getuser.aspx?username =alex.hardman

The first URL (via MVC) is more human readable and search engine friendly (e.g. all things equal would be ranked higher by all the main search engines).

ii)     The second advantage with having full control over url’s relates to the current drive in Digital Humanities research for data preservation. Without going into too much detail one aspect of data preservation involves the creation of “permanent url’s” and “unique resource identifiers” (uri’s).  The standard use of session variables and view state in web forms means that the same url can refer to a multiple items of data (where query parameters are input via view state). The result is that data accessed in this manor data doesn’t have a unique resource identifier (i.e. a unique address on the web). This means data items can’t be referenced as it doesn’t have a unique address on the web and prevents its inclusion in Linked Data initiatives and other research initiatives requiring a URI.

The combination of URI and the ease at which a system can return computer readable data formats such as XML (see above) puts a developer at an advantage when it comes to best practice in Humanities data curation and preservation techniques. At the recent Oxford ‘Research databases in the humanities – where next?’ workshop there was a strong emphasis upon curating Humanities research data with uri’s, and computer readable data formats. This is something that we could ‘sell’ as distinctly advantageous to our research clients.

Comment: The OP had that short timespan -over two years ago-. But, still, useful for other people stumbling upon this question. Consider reformatting your question and using markup to make sample code and urls and headings more easy to locate and read. =)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [ASP.NET MVC Training Kit](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=1E0BE0B2-910A-4676-9F3A-41E4D9C0FC08&displaylang=en).

It includes a pre-canned (albeit 60 minute) presentation that you can hack around with.

It focuses on:

- Seperation of Concerns
- Testability
- Control

I actually did something similar (although it was about 45 - 60 minutes including demo) just before this came out, and the key take home for us was really:

> It gives you back control of the HTML mark-up.

The testability etc was fairly understood already, but that was seen as a key benefit over standard ASP.NET.

Comment: Thanks Zhaph - I'll have a look at that

Answer (score 2):

You've gotten all sorts of points - my question is, why do you think you want to use it in the first place, and how do you think it will help you and the rest of the development team in your environment?  The bullet points are useless if they don't apply to your situation.

Answer (score 1):

Explain them that:

1. There are no server controls anymore
2. There is no event-mechanism anymore
3. There is no ViewState anymore
4. Now they won't get away with comfortable WebForms and will have to learn the basics of HTTP, HTML/CSS and JavaScript

Prepare some medicines for those who will faint.

(5). Now it is not about pages, but about resources (REST model). URL will not point to a physical file (.aspx) but to a controller action which may serve back different kinds of responses - a page to render, a short xml as an Ajax response etc.

P.S. If you have something like company-internal framework which facilitates many common operations and it is built with WebForms, you will likely not persuade them to adopt MVC since it means lots of work, dramatic changes in the thought patterns and likely a significant amount of time/costs.

EDIT: For those who asked for positive points...

(6). SEO-friendly Urls out of the box, without the need for third party utilities for Url rewriting.

(7). Complete control over your HTML output. No ViewState payload, no injection of auto-generated IDs => clean markup + smaller pages sizes => less traffic consumption + shorter response times.

(8). A possibility for a clean transparent design of an application (even with multiple layers). Instead of hacking with each control separately in code behind, you are in a better position now to design an architecture with understandable and traceable flow of data - from the database layer over business logic until it reaches the view. Much better compared to ubiquitous WebForms coding style when each control goes directly into the database to get some data to display. Not necessarily that you manage a clean design, but at least the MVC concept makes it cleaner for you now how to do it right.

Comment: All negative points and no positive ones.  Thats going to be a miserable 15 minute presentation.  All of this taken away for what benefit.  In 15 minutes benefits and key new concepts are really all you have time for.

Answer (score 1):

I'd grab their attention with routing, that's the most obvious stuff (and it is not confined to MVC). I'd then look at the higher level view and talk about separation of concerns, testability and mockability.

If I were you I'd head over to [ScottGu's](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) blog and use his excellent material:-)

Answer (score 1):

The best way to do this is follow ScottGuthries Sample Chapter in Professional ASP.NET MVC 1.0, where he's given a walkthrough of developing a full-fledged web application using ASP.NET MVC with all features. You can summarize that chapter in 20 minutes.

[image]

Download the Sample Chapter By Scott Guthrie [Here](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html)!

LinkText: http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/id-321793.html

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

If they have been using ASP.NET they might not be familiar with the MVC architecture to begin with and you might have to talk about that a little bit.

Since they are all developers and you have only 15 minutes, I would suggest you show them File > New for ASP.NET MVC project and briefly talk about the scaffolding. That's a big sell for MVC in that it works off the go and you are already set up for iterative development.

After that you could switch to a working demo of a simple application. For this I would step through the application with a debugger from routing in global.asax to controller action to model and eventually back up to the view. This will bring up interesting questions and explain the new application life cycle including SoC, MVC, L2S, etc. This will also implicitly highlight the differences between ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET applications.

If you have wfetch (or Fiddler or Live HTTP Headers) then I would show the client side request as well and highlight the absence of view states and highligh the POST/GET verbs (PUT/DELETE if you are using wfetch). Maybe mention the usefulness of this in AJAX apps.

Anticipate questions on how to migrate the current app and what the value proposition is for your current use-case scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

A blog in 15mins :-). Seriously, maybe focus on the seperation of concerns ?

Comment: I think he was saying: Write a Blog (Software) in 15 Minutes using MVC.

Comment: Yes, that's what made rails famous a couple of years ago.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse the first and most important thing is separation of concepts, which gives:
1.More transparent design which is easier to understand and manage.
2.Convention over configuration. Which speeds up development and reduces coding/design practice differences among developers.
3.Development patern already weaven into application design itself:
You develop models, then controller, then views. Change and test them separately(maybe with dedicated developers).

But let me say if they given you only 15 minutes they really dont want to hear about it or use it for that matter ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think that generally best approach when you want to present some new technology is to make a simple example that will explain some of the cool features.

You can create example of simple mvc application with 2 different views of the same page and 2 different controllers. One controller you can use for async operations and second for normal requesting. One view can be normal view, second view can be view optimized for mobile phones. It is few hours of work and with this example you can cover all of the cool features of asp.net mvc:

-routing
-testability
-flexibility and Separation of Concern

cheers

Answer (score 0):

In reality 15mins isn’t enough to really drill into any of the benefits you get out of MVC. I’m guessing the person you working with is most familiar with Asp.net Web Forms. Without digging too design patterns and why MVC is great, the most comprehensible thing to go over will be easy use of Ajax.

```
1. jQuery – Ajax
2.  Routing – SEO and No need for Custom URL rewriting 
3.  Partial-View – showing tabular data and use server-side Ajax to sort and a client side example using jQuery
```

Most often when I go into shops that have been developing Web Forms the most common question is where are my controls; more specifically where is the repeater or datagrid? Putting together this type of demo would give as much as you can in 15mins and answer the more common questions.